# set tooltips on each column in nodeview gtk# monodevelop under linux

Tags: linux, tooltip, monodevelop, gtk#

I want to set tooltips for a nodeview in gtk# using monodevelop under Linux, but I can't specify it for each column header, I need to explain the meaning of each column ...

Please, help me??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a widget into a column header and set tooltip to the widget:

```
    Label label = new Label("Column header");
    label.TooltipText = "Column tooltip";
    nodeview.GetColumn(0).Widget = label;
```